# How to save a game's progress in c++ (visual studio)

Tags: c++, windows

I am making a game, the game works, but when I exit the console application, I want the game to save the user's progress, such as money and items they have bought. I am not sure how to, I am new to c++.
Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Comment: You save it in a file in an easily readable format, and read it back when you start the next time.

Comment: Ok, how do I do that. Sorry im new

Comment: The best start is to get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and read about files.

Comment: i have edited my questions. does that code work?

Comment: What is `FileInput`? Is it a class that you made, or just your guess at how input/output could've worker?

Comment: To be honest I have copied that code, from another forum with a similar question and tried to adapt that code to my game. But I do not understand it.

Comment: you have to make up your mind what you want to write to the file and in which format, most of this is not specific to C++. Once you know what you want in the file you can turn to implementing it in C++

Comment: How do i do that in code?

Comment: just google: how to read file in c++ and how to write file in c++. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

To save progression you need to create a saveFile, you have to define what variables to save (money, items, current life, posX, posY,...).

You can define any readable file format like JSON :

```
{
     "player":{
         "life":26,
         "max_life":40,
         "bag":{
             "max_number_items":15
             "items":[..,..,..]
}
```

Or anything else like this:

```
<PLAYER>
max_life=40
life=26
</PLAYER>
<BAG>
max_number_items
..
</BAG>
```

And then on load, you have to read your file to get back your data